# WifiManager.setWifiEnabled not working correctly on honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, wifimanager

I'm busy writing a little program to automate my wifi on my 3.1 honeycomb tab and my 2.3.5 gingerbread phone.

Everything works great on the phone, but when my app tries to disable my wifi on honeycomb it fc's.

My app basically sets and alarm to fire a custom broadcast which is then catched by my broadcast receiver. I can confirm that the broadcast is fired and is cough, but it would seem that honeycomb throws an runtime exception when it runs .setWiFiEnabled(false). I have check the permissions and they look correct. (It is working in gb).

Here is some of my code to try and explain better.

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <receiver android:name="WiFiOffDoerReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="za.co.cjoliver.WIFIOFFDOER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Code

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class WiFiOffDoerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("WiFi Beater3", "in WiFiOffDoerReceiver.onReceive");
    WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    myWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
}
```

}

Let me say thank you already for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'mot sure exactly what you issue is but it sounds like it has something to do with your ROM, if it's rooted or not, etc.

Another possibility is the API you're using.  Does HC require a different version than GB?

I don't think it's your code, so if you can't figure it out, try providing info about the difference between the tab and phone (besides the obvious).

Just a hunch, so I'm sorry if it's way off base.

Good luck!

Comment: Both are running custom roms. Will restore both to stock and test again. Will update once i have tested. THX